# Pass file as input to a program and store its output using the sh library in python

Tags: python, mapreduce, sh

I'm confused on how exactly we should use the python `sh` library, specifically the `sh.Command()`. Basically, I wish to pass `input_file_a` to `program_b.py` and store its output in a different directory as `output_file_b`, how should I achieve this using the `sh` library in python?

Comment: Is there a reason you specifically want to use the `sh` third party library? There's functions in standard Python libraries that allow you to do this just fine and you appear to be fairly inexperienced?

Comment: Also, it would help if you, apart from indicating why you're trying to use `sh` (and what you've tried alread), would explain what problem you're trying to solve exactly - there may be better ways of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean input and output redirection, then see [here (in)](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/sections/stdin.html) and [here (out)](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/sections/redirection.html#redirection) respectively. In particular, looks like to "redirect" stdin you need to pass as argument the actual bytes (e.g. read them beforehand), in particular, the following should work according to their documentation (untested, as I don't have/work with sh - please let know if this works for you / fix whatever is missing):

```py
import sh
python3 = sh.Command("python3")
with open(input_file_a, 'r') as ifile:
    python3("program_b.py", _in=ifile.read(), _out=output_file_b)
```

Note that may need to specify argument `search_paths`  for sh.Command for it to find python. Also, may need to specify full path to `program_b.py` file or `os.chdir()` accordingly.